# Spawn a new EC2 Instance if any process in the Instance is down

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a java process on AWS. It is not dockerised for business reasons. But if the process goes down. It should spawn a new EC2 instance. Is this possible with Cloud watch?

Comment: why is it down voted. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer in the below link. AWS Cloud watch will help us monitor applications and reboot EC2 instance if application doesn't respond.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-amazon-cloudwatch-action-reboot-ec2-instance/

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is AWS Autoscaling.

> AWS Auto Scaling is a service that automatically monitors and adjusts
>   compute resources to maintain performance for applications hosted in
>   the Amazon Web Services (AWS) public cloud.

Essentially what it does is, it integrates with AWS Cloud Watch to set alarms for specific situations.

For example, if the instance gets hit with x number of requests within a time period of y mins. Or for example, the health check of an instance fails (your situation).

When you are launching your EC2 instance, explore and check out Autoscaling groups and Launch Configuration. Check out this link below
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/GettingStartedTutorial.html

Now you mentioned that there is a process which is running in your EC2 instance.
Launch Configurations give you a way to provide a bash script which is executed when your instance starts.

This bash script should contain the logic to pull your business logic from wherever you are hosting it, and then run that process.

Let me know if you have any confusions.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will not use auto scale but just a reboot of EC2 instance.